# FPDF: Rotate Output

Tags: php, fpdf

I've created wit FPDF an PDF. In order to print the PDF automatically, I need to rotate each page in a 90 degree angle. I searched everything on the web - nothing. Has anyone rotated the output of FPDF?

Thanks!

Comment: The third parameter of [`AddPage()`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/addpage.htm) allows to rotate the page.

Comment: You may also define the size of the page in landscape dimensions instead of letter dimensions.